# Why does NOT using self in a Class Method work when the object is created without parenthesis after class name?

Tags: python, class, self

In this example the method **speak** inside the class bird has no 'self' parameter.
When creating the object sparrow I have not given parenthesis after the class name.
The Program runs fine. But I had assumed the SELF argument is a must.
However the same does not work if I create an Object like this --> sparrow bird()
Now since I have used Parenthesis after class name, I will need SELF argument inside the method **speak**

```
class bird:
    color='Brown'
    def speak():            #NOT using SELF
        return 'Chirp Chirp'
sparrow = bird              #NO parenthesis being used after class name
print(sparrow.color)
print (sparrow.speak())
```

Comment: `sparrow = bird` does *NOT* create an object; you just now have an additional name referring to the class itself.

Comment: …and `speak` here is a class method, not an instance method, so no need for `self`.

Comment: Thanks... now I get it

Answer (score 0):

You need a `self` parameter in the method when the method is called on an instance of the class.

You aren't calling the method on an instance though, you're calling it on the class itself. This:

```
sparrow = bird
print(sparrow.speak())
```

Is the same thing as just:

```
print(bird.speak())
```

`sparrow = bird` essentially just created a second name for the `bird` class. That isn't creating an instance.

When calling a method on a class, no arguments are implicitly passed, so `self` isn't needed.